# flutter table column width is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-table

Below is my Code

```
child: Table(
               // defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(140.0),
                columnWidths: {
                  0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                  1: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                  2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                  3: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                },
```

default column width is working but not flex column width..